# Не могу понять что за проблемы с кодировкой?

Tags: c, кодировка, visual-c++, c++, строки

Найти в тексте все слова (не содержащие пробелов последовательности символов), содержащие символы из более чем одного из четырёх алфавитов: русских букв, латинских букв, цифр, символов (математических символов и знаков пунктуации).

Вот что сделал

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
    printf("INPUT:\n");
    char s[100];
    scanf("%[^\n]s",s);
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(s)-1;i++)
     {
         if(s[i]==' ' && ((s[i+1]>='A'&& s[i+1]<='Z' && s[i+1]>='А' && s[i+1]<='Я') || (s[i+1]>='a'&& s[i+1]<='z' && s[i+1]>=-128 && s[i+1]<=-17)) )
             count++;
     }
    printf("RESULT-%d",count);
    _getch();
```

}
Когда ввожу слова с русскими и латинскими буквами по отдельности всё Работает
Работает когда ввожу последовательность типа "SSSЯЯЯЯ"
Но, когда ввожу последовательность "ЯЯЯЯJJJJ" то слово игнорируется почему не могу понять

Comment: @factura, что значит "игнорируется"? Какой результат выводится?

Comment: разбейте код на функции. Так вам проще будет с ним работать. А пока что он больше напоминает регулярное выражение

Comment: В условии ошибка. Символ не может быть одновременно русской и латинской буквой, а у вас там &&. Надо учесть, что русский алфавит представлен по-разному в разных кодировках, большие буквы тоже отрицательные и т.п.

Comment: paulgri, слово просто не подсчитывается

Comment: Альтернативы:

1. Подобные задачи - это лексический анализ, хорошо решаются автоматами.

2. Запишите все ожидаемый символы в массивы, если надо по категориям, и ищите с помощью strchr().

Comment: Я бы рад но для нашего препода strchr() читерство, потоеи тоже, всё должно быть написано своими руками)))

Comment: Да и математические символы, имхо, звучит как-то двусмысленно. то ли имеются в виду символы больше\меньше\равно\не равно, то ли какие-то извращения из таблицы символов юникода

Comment: Напишите свою функцию типа strchr() :) или препод и это не приемлет?

Comment: @SoloMio никто ничего поэтому поводу не говорит

Comment: Вас точно не смущают диапазоны в условиях? Для краткости заменю s[i+1] на X: x>='A' && x<='Z' && x>='А' && x<='Я'. То есть одновременно и в русской части и в английской.

Comment: @Alexey123,меня смущает, но как осуществить подсчёт не понимаю

Comment: @factura, насколько понял Вы хотите увеличить `count`, когда текузий символ это пробел и следующий это любая буква. Если так, то напишите функцию, проверяющую, является ли символ буквой и все упростится

     if (s[i] == ' ' && isany_cp1251_letter(s[i + 1))
       count++;

а функция для кодировки cp1251 очевидна


    static inline int isany_cp1251_letter (char c) {
      return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') 
             || c == 'ё' || c == 'Ё' 
             || (unsigned char)c >= (unsigned char)'А'; // русская
    }


И все должно заработать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас неверный подход к решению задачи. В условии сказано, что последовательность символов без пробелов должна состоять из более чем одного алфавита. Каждый символ в последовательности может быть только в одном алфавите, нужно будет проверить все символы к принадлежности:

1. русский: [А-Яа-я]
2. латинский: [A-Za-z]
3. цифры: [1-9]
4. мат. символы и пунктуация [.,<>!+-=
       и т.д.]

Или в условиях:

1. русский: s[i]>='А'&& s[i]<='Я' ||
       s[i]>='а' && s[i]<='я'
2. латинский: s[i]>='A'&& s[i]<='Z' ||
       s[i]>='a' && s[i]<='z'
3. цифры: s[i]>='1'&& s[i]<='9'
4. мат. символы и пунктуация(уточняйте
       этот диапазон, я взял часть):
       s[i]>=33 && s[i]<=47

Задача пройтись по строке и найти последовательности и выяснить к какому алфавиту принадлежат символы:

```
int rus = 0, 
    eng = 0, 
    num = 0, 
    math = 0, 
    next = 0; /*это переменная для пропуска нужна будет*/

for(int i=0;i<strlen(s)-1;i++){
     /*если это не последовательность и встретили пробел, то она закончилась, сбрасываем счетчики и идем дальше*/
         if(s[i]==' '){
        rus = 0; 
        eng = 0; 
        num = 0; 
        math = 0; 
        next = 0;
        continue;
     }

    /*если последовательность, то проверяем каждый символ*/
    if(s[i]>='А'&& s[i]<='Я' || s[i]>='а' && s[i]<='я') rus=1;
    if(s[i]>='A'&& s[i]<='Z' || s[i]>='a' && s[i]<='z') eng=1;
    if(s[i]>='1'&& s[i]<='9') num=1;
    if(s[i]>=33 && s[i]<=47) math=1;

    /*теперь проверяем накопленные данные*/
    if(rus + eng + num + math > 2){
        /*мы нашли нужную*/
        if(next==0) {
            count++;
            next=1; //заглушка, что бы не посчитать второй раз, она сбросится при пробеле
        }
    }
}
```

Это основная идея решения задачи, код я не проверял, он демонстративный. Ваша задача теперь в нем разобраться и написать решение на основе того, какие выводы сделаете.